# Scrapy installation fails while installing cryptography package

Tags: python-2.7, installation, scrapy, pip

I am trying to install scrapy with "pip install scrapy" . I followed the instructions as mentioned on http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/install.html#intro-install-platform-notes. It first starts downloading packages and running setup.py for each but fails while trying to install cryptography package. Does any one know how to resolve this issue. Here is my complete traceback:

```
    C:\Users\Mubashar Kamran>pip install scrapy
    Downloading/unpacking scrapy
  Downloading Scrapy-0.24.4.tar.gz (783kB): 783kB downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package scrapy

    no previously-included directories found matching 'docs\build'
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Twisted>=10.0.0 in c:\
python27\lib\site-packages (from scrapy)
Downloading/unpacking w3lib>=1.8.0 (from scrapy)
  Downloading w3lib-1.10.0.tar.gz
  Running setup.py egg_info for package w3lib

Downloading/unpacking queuelib (from scrapy)
  Downloading queuelib-1.2.2.tar.gz
  Running setup.py egg_info for package queuelib

Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): lxml in c:\python27\li
b\site-packages (from scrapy)
Downloading/unpacking pyOpenSSL (from scrapy)
  Downloading pyOpenSSL-0.14.tar.gz (128kB): 128kB downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package pyOpenSSL

    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in dis
tribution
    no previously-included directories found matching 'doc\_build'
Downloading/unpacking cssselect>=0.9 (from scrapy)
  Downloading cssselect-0.9.1.tar.gz
  Running setup.py egg_info for package cssselect

    no previously-included directories found matching 'docs\_build'
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): six>=1.5.2 in c:\pytho
n27\lib\site-packages (from scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): zope.interface>=3.6.0
in c:\python27\lib\site-packages (from Twisted>=10.0.0->scrapy)
Downloading/unpacking cryptography>=0.2.1 (from pyOpenSSL->scrapy)
  Downloading cryptography-0.5.4.tar.gz (320kB): 320kB downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package cryptography
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 16, in <module>
      File "c:\users\mubash~1\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_Mubashar Kamran\crypt
ography\setup.py", line 174, in <module>
        "test": PyTest,
      File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\core.py", line 112, in setup
        _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
      File "build\bdist.win32\egg\setuptools\dist.py", line 239, in __init__
      File "build\bdist.win32\egg\setuptools\dist.py", line 263, in fetch_build_
eggs
      File "build\bdist.win32\egg\pkg_resources.py", line 568, in resolve
        if entry is None:
      File "build\bdist.win32\egg\pkg_resources.py", line 806, in best_match
        is returned.
      File "build\bdist.win32\egg\pkg_resources.py", line 818, in obtain

      File "build\bdist.win32\egg\setuptools\dist.py", line 313, in fetch_build_
egg
      File "build\bdist.win32\egg\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 609,
 in easy_install

      File "build\bdist.win32\egg\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 639,
 in install_item

      File "build\bdist.win32\egg\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 825,
 in install_eggs

      File "build\bdist.win32\egg\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1031
, in build_and_install

      File "build\bdist.win32\egg\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1019
, in run_setup

    distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Setup script exited with error: Unable to f
ind vcvarsall.bat
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 16, in <module>

  File "c:\users\mubash~1\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_Mubashar Kamran\cryptogra
phy\setup.py", line 174, in <module>

    "test": PyTest,

  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\core.py", line 112, in setup

    _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)

  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\setuptools\dist.py", line 239, in __init__

  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\setuptools\dist.py", line 263, in fetch_build_eggs


  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\pkg_resources.py", line 568, in resolve

    if entry is None:

  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\pkg_resources.py", line 806, in best_match

    is returned.

  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\pkg_resources.py", line 818, in obtain



  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\setuptools\dist.py", line 313, in fetch_build_egg

  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 609, in
easy_install



  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 639, in
install_item



  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 825, in
install_eggs



  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1031, in
 build_and_install



  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1019, in
 run_setup



distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Setup script exited with error: Unable to find
vcvarsall.bat

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in c:\users\mubash~1\a
ppdata\local\temp\pip_build_Mubashar Kamran\cryptography
Storing complete log in C:\Users\Mubashar Kamran\pip\pip.log

C:\Users\Mubashar Kamran>
```

Comment: have you checked [this SO topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817869/error-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat) ?

Comment: is VS necessary for this installation? i have although checked my control panel . It has visual c++ 2008 redistributable